# Using AWS SDK and AWS session provider with dotnet core

Tags: session, amazon-web-services, .net-core

I want to port an existing ASP.net MVC 5 web application to dotnet core and asp.net core.

The application uses the AWS session provider for session management and I would ideally like to use this or some similar alternative.

At the moment the AWS SDK does not seem to support dotnet core and I can't find too much information on this.

Does anybody know (a) if and when AWS SDK will be compatible with dotnet core or alternatively (b) if there is another nosql-based session provider similar to the AWS session provider that I can use instead?

Thanks